# fetch facebook comments by cannonical url

Tags: facebook, url

In our custom CMS we are having lots of facebook comments and shares bound to slugs generated from article titles.
Now things are getting bad and comments and/or shares bound to different title slugs are getting lost.
Every time someone changes article title in the backend ( admin ), a new parallel universe of comments/shares are created.
I could setup my own permalink using current title, but things are messed up and I would rather bind to facebook crawled cannonical url if possible.

Cannonical url is defined by

```
<meta property="og:url" content="@String.Format("http://www.index.hr/tema/{0}/permalink-{1}", Model.Theme.Id, Model.Article.Id)" />
```

I have tried to fetch comments using this cannonical permalink, but get nothing back. 
If it is not possible is it somehow possible to redefine bound links at facebook?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1149655968420144